# C# Inconsistent Accessibility (Multiple Classes)

Tags: c#, class

I am getting an Inconsistent Accessibility problem where I have one class that contains a List of another class

```
namespace NS {
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.bar = new List<Bar>();
    }
    private List<Bar> bar;
}
public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
    }
}
}
```

The error is property type NS.Bar is less accessible than property NS.Foo.Bar

The structure to the application is each Foo consists of a Dynamic Array (List) of Bar.  It's not ecommerce but the best example would be an eCommerce Store->Categories->Products in terms of how the data will be accessed.

Comment: You are missing the part of your code that gives the error. The code you posted is just fine.

Comment: what is the signature of NS.Foo.Bar property, your listing only the variable

Comment: Are you sure your code sample is correct? It looks like that should work and the error message does not make any sense (NS.Bar is public so it cannot be less accessible than anything and there is no property NS.Foo.Bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get any compile errors and you shouldn't either, have you tried cleaning or rebuilding the project before trying it again? Since Bar is public you should have no problem using it in any other class.

Comment: You are right, the error disappeared when I rebuilt it. I thought it was right as i've come across the error before when the classes aren't public.

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, please kindly accept it as the answer please. I'm glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have pasted the correct code? Because this error usually arises when the Type used in the property is actually less accessible than a property itself. Maybe You have forgotten to put an access classifier (so it's internal by default) and you get this error. Check the code again.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, your real code looks like this:

```
namespace NS
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            this.Bar = new List<Bar>();
        }

        public List<Bar> Bar {get;set;}
    }

    internal class Bar
    {
        public Bar()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the problem is, that the public property `Bar` of the public class `Foo` returns a list of instances of the **internal** class `Bar`.

Comment: Bar should probably be internal as private classes must be nested inside another class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "Bar" class is public.  If it's not explicitly stated public, it might be considered private or protected.